# Redirect after signing out of ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to redirect users to my root_path which is `/` and allowed for unauthenticated users, but I can't seem to be able to change the default behavior of `active admin`.

I know `active admin` uses `devise` as the authentication mechanism, but I could not override the defaults for `devise` either.

I tried the following in my `application_controller.rb` (even though it's supposed to be the default):

```
# Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  root_path
end
```

But I still see this in my logs:

```
Started GET "/admin/logout?locale=fr" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-07 11:30:15 -0400
  Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"fr"}
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE `admin_users` SET `remember_created_at` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2012-06-07 15:30:15' WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin
Completed 302 Found in 47ms
```

So it sends me back to the login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a monkey patch for this

```
module ActiveAdmin::Devise::Controller

      def root_path
        "/"  #add your logic
      end
end
```

add this to initializers and it must force redirection to root url after logout.

Answer (score 6):

Fivell answer is slighty incorrect, because also login is redirected to root_path. Even better, you could override the specific Devise method:

```ruby
ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController.class_eval do
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    "/wherever-you-want"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
# in app/admin/override.rb
ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController.class_eval do
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    admin_dashboard_path
  end

  def root_path
    "/"  #add your logic
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    root_path
  end
end
```